# How can I make site.co site.com site.in site.info site.me all point to the same hosting provider

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I have several top level domains registered, how do I make all these domains point to one single domain through DNS (is this possible or should I do a redirect?)

i.e. my site.info is up an running with dreamhost

how do i point all the other domains .co, .com etc., to the .info in DNS..

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point all your domain names to your webserver. You can use a CNAME record for www.site.com (pointing to site.info), but you must use an A record (i.e. an IP address) for site.com.

You then have two options for the webserver setup. You can either treat all hostnames as the same site (i.e. your site is served on all the hostnames), or you can redirect all other hostnames to your canonical hostname. The latter is generally preferred (consistently named links to your site and better search engine indexing).

Comment: Cool, Thanks mgorven. I did this but get 'error id: "bad_httpd_conf"' when I reach the site through .com... Probably Dreamhost (where I host .info) filters based on the address. .info works fine though

Comment: Ok I have more details on the bad_http_conf: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Bad_httpd_conf

Comment: Did you configure DreamHost with the extra domains (for HTTP)?

Answer (score 1):

CNAME DNS records.

You could use A records as well, but you'd have to manually change all of them if you change the web server ip address.

Comment: Except that you can't CNAME the root of a zone, so A records are your only option there.

Comment: I should have read the question more carefully. Thanks for the assist.